# Move magento from one url to another

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, server

I have developed a site in the url www.example.com/demo on now i want to move the site to www.example.com on the same server what are the steps that are to be taken to move the site on the same server with the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy all the files from demo folder to root folder. Since Database configuration in file will be same, so you don't need to change those. In database Run this query

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

change base secure and unsecure url to www.example.com.

Clear the cache and your are ready with www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify database table core_config_data
In that set path web/unsecure/base_url value www.example.com
AND web/secure/base_url value = www.example.com

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change only two things in the Magento backend:

1. `System >> Configuration >> Web >> Unsecure >> Base URL` to new url.
2. `System >> Configuration >> Web >> Secure >> Base URL` to new url.

Comment: Buddy its not working we can do it by using database